# How to check the RegionRestriction of a Channel using youtube API

Tags: youtube-api, google-apis-explorer

Is there any option exists in the Youtube API to check whether a channel is blocked in a country. For Video, in the API there is the item value " Region Restriction" {'blocked':['IN']}. But nothing for the Channel so far. Want to check whether a channel is restricted or not using the Youtube API

Answer (score 3):

The solution can be found on the JSON of the video in question. To find the countries where the video is unavailable, it searches for the term "regionRestriction" in the JSON of the video. Here is the code I built which allows you to display the countries (with Python):

```
import requests,json
api_key = 'tap_your_api_code'
url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=mCChxHZXacA&part=contentDetails&key={api_key}"
dictio_data = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)
contentDetails_json = dictio_data["items"][0]["contentDetails"]["regionRestriction"]["blocked"]
print(contentDetails_json)
```

Result:

```
['AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AI', 'AL', 'AM', 'AO', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AW', 'AX', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BM', 'BN', 'BO', 'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BW', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CA', 'CC', 'CD', 'CF', 'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'CK', 'CL', 'CM', 'CN', 'CO', 'CR', 'CU', 'CV', 'CX', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DJ', 'DK', 'DM', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ER', 'ES', 'ET', 'FI', 'FJ', 'FK', 'FM', 'FO', 'FR', 'GA', 'GB', 'GD', 'GE', 'GF', 'GG', 'GH', 'GI', 'GL', 'GM', 'GN', 'GP', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GS', 'GT', 'GU', 'GW', 'GY', 'HK', 'HN', 'HR', 'HT', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IM', 'IN', 'IO', 'IQ', 'IR', 'IS', 'IT', 'JE', 'JM', 'JO', 'JP', 'KE', 'KG', 'KH', 'KI', 'KM', 'KN', 'KP', 'KR', 'KW', 'KY', 'KZ', 'LA', 'LB', 'LC', 'LI', 'LK', 'LR', 'LS', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'LY', 'MA', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MG', 'MH', 'MK', 'ML', 'MM', 'MN', 'MO', 'MP', 'MQ', 'MR', 'MS', 'MT', 'MU', 'MV', 'MW', 'MX', 'MY', 'MZ', 'NA', 'NC', 'NE', 'NF', 'NG', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NP', 'NR', 'NU', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PF', 'PG', 'PH', 'PK', 'PL', 'PM', 'PN', 'PR', 'PS', 'PT', 'PW', 'PY', 'QA', 'RE', 'RO', 'RS', 'RU', 'RW', 'SA', 'SB', 'SC', 'SD', 'SE', 'SG', 'SH', 'SI', 'SJ', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN', 'SO', 'SR', 'ST', 'SV', 'SY', 'SZ', 'TC', 'TD', 'TG', 'TH', 'TJ', 'TK', 'TL', 'TM', 'TN', 'TO', 'TR', 'TT', 'TV', 'TW', 'TZ', 'UA', 'UG', 'UM', 'US', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VA', 'VC', 'VE', 'VG', 'VI', 'VN', 'VU', 'WF', 'WS', 'YE', 'YT', 'ZA', 'ZM', 'ZW']
```